# Is it possible to subscribe inside a `zipWith` operator?

Tags: android, rx-java2

I am using RxJava2 and have a Flowable function like this

```
Flowable1
  .doOnNext()
  .toList()
  .onErrorReturnItem()
  .zipWith(Flowable2
             .toList()
             .onErrorReturnItem()){
         condition1 -> return list1
         condition2 -> return list2

         return list3
   }
  .flattenAsFlowable()
  .flatMap()
```

In the `zipWith` operator I have conditions that return different lists depending on the result. And actually, the final flatMap is meant only for `list3`. But I can't formulate how to have it inside the `zipWith()` operator while still continuing the sequence. I am thinking that I would still need to subscribe if I wrap it inside the `zipWith` operator which would result into jumbled threads

Is there a way around it?

Comment: It is not clear what are you trying to achieve exactly?
what is the list3?
on what params the conditions depend on?

Answer (score 0):

After a few hours, I have finally formulated a way to return from a list form a flowable within zipWith:

```
Flowable1
  .doOnNext()
  .toList()
  .onErrorReturnItem()
  .zipWith(Flowable2
             .toList()
             .onErrorReturnItem()){
         condition1 -> return list1
         condition2 -> return list2

         return Flowable.fromtIterable(list3)
                    .flatMap()
                    .toList()
                    .blockingGet()
   }
  .flattenAsFlowable()
```